# Monthly Loan Calculation using Math.Pow

Tags: c#, webforms, pow

I am attempting to calculate a monthly loan payment using this formula:

[image: Loan Formula]

Where L is the loan amount, R is the monthly interest rate, and N is the number of payments.

First I get the input from the web app and do the calculations to get it into the right format for the formula:

```
double loanAmount = double.Parse(txtLoanAmount.Text) - double.Parse(txtDownPayment.Text);
double interestRate = (double.Parse(txtInterestRate.Text) / 100) / 12;  
double loanPeriod = double.Parse(txtLoanPeriod.SelectedValue) * 12;
```

Then here is how I currently have the formula written:

```
Answer = loanAmount * interestRate / 1 - Math.Pow(1 / 1 + interestRate, loanPeriod);
```

I'm not too overly familiar with the math.pow function (think I've used it once before), so I'm not sure if I am using it properly. If anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Math.Pow(value, power), you need to take care of the operator precedence, i.e. multiplication and division before addition and subtraction, use brackets whenever possible.

Comment: Don't mix integer math and floating point. You should be typing `1.0` instead of `1` (there is a difference). Also if you are interested in precision, use the `decimal` type instead of `double`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in some of the previous comments, operator precedence is going to be an issue in your code.

From my understanding of your formula, you'll want it to read like this;

```
Answer = (loanAmount * interestRate) / (1.0 - Math.Pow(1.0 / 1.0 + interestRate, loanPeriod));
```

This should get your precedence correct, as well as dealing with any floating point math issues that could arise (note the change from `1` -> `1.0`)

As mentioned by Ron in the comments, you may want to also consider changing from `double` to `decimal` for precision.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It helped get me closer to the answer, needed to also throw in negative in front of the power and it got my the correct number!